# How can I get the background color of a selected element?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

In Swing when using a JTree/JList/JTable selecting an item changes its background color. Is there any way to retrieve this color for the current look and feel when the component is not selected? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBackground")
```

Other useful values are:

```
UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionForeground")
UIManager.getColor("Tree.textBackground")
UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground")
```

**EDIT:** The other solutions proposed work of course but the downside is that you need a component and it has to be selected before you can call the method or you'll get the non-selected background. This solution can be called even if you don't have a tree to begin with :)

Comment: Cool, this is probably it. Is there a list of keys that are available somewhere?

Comment: I asked this question myself many times and i never remember what the answer was :) I think there is a list somewhere but i can't remember off the top of my head. A little googling will get you there though... :)

Comment: @sandro Full list of keys is dependent on LAF in use. You can get them using the following code: `for (Map.Entry entry : UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().entrySet()){System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue()} `

Comment: Or, if you are interested in the keys of a particular look and feel, you can look directly at the source code of the look and feel class. e.g. the class WindowsLookAndFeel.

Answer (score 2):

For a list of all the UIManager values see [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/).

Answer (score 0):

[getBackground()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBackground()) should return you the current color of any component

Comment: Thank you, but I need the color before it is selected.